# Running R console in remote ssh'd desktop using SublimeREPL

Tags: r, sublimetext2

I love Sublime Text 2, and love SublimeREPL's ability to run a console within it.

I'm wondering whether it's possible to run that console on a remote desktop through ssh.

I've tried modifying the sublimeREPL package settings to point to an external machine:
`//"default_extend_env":{"PATH":"{PATH};username@remotemachine:R"}`

Unfortunately, that didn't work; when I ran sublimeREPL it just went right back to the local copy of R. (I'm running Mac OS X)

Any way to run SublimeREPL's console on a remote machine? Ideally graphical output would get X-forwarded back to the local machine, but that's not totally necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late reply:

In this file:
https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/blob/master/config/R/Main.sublime-menu try changing lines 21 to

```
  "osx": ["ssh", "yourlogin@yourserver", "R", "--interactive", "--no-readline"],
```

It's a hack but somehow works for me :)

Also:

```
  "osx": ["ssh", "-Y",  "yourlogin@yourserver", "R", "--interactive", "--no-readline"],[/code]
```

might or might not forward graphical output. Try it.

Comment: It works for linux too `"linux": ["ssh", etc etc ]`. Read here for more details [https://www.r-bloggers.com/set-up-sublime-text-for-light-weight-all-in-one-data-science-ide/]